# Finding cylindrical harmonics coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, bessel-functions

I have a (known) function $f(\rho,\phi)$ that is valid for $|\rho|>a$ (and it satifies laplace's equation)

I want to decompose it into

$$f(\rho,\phi)=\sum _{\nu\ :\ odd}C\nu J\nu(k\rho)\sin(\nu\phi)+D\nu Y\nu(k\rho)\sin(\nu\phi)$$

($\nu$ is odd because $f(\rho,\phi)=0$ for $\phi=0$ or $\phi=\pi$ and it is symmetric wrt $\frac{\pi}{2}$)

I could not find an orthogonality relation for the bessel functions that would help me. How can the coefficients be determined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $1-\cos^2\phi$ vanishes for $\phi=0$ and $\phi=\pi$. Is it odd?

Otherwise $C_{\nu}J_{\nu}(k\rho)+D_{\nu}Y_{\nu}(k\rho)$ is just $\nu$th Fourier coefficient in the expansion of $f(\rho,\phi)$ with respect to $\phi$. In other words, to decompose you only need orthogonality of exponentials $e^{i\nu\phi}$, not orthogonality of Bessel functions.

Namely, given $f(\rho,\phi)$, we can write it as
$$f(\rho,\phi)=\sum_{\nu\in\mathbb Z}f_{\nu}(\rho)e^{i\nu \phi},$$
where
$$f_{\nu}(\rho)=\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(\rho,\phi)e^{-i\nu\phi}d\phi.\tag{1}$$
Now if $f(\rho,\phi)$ satisfies Laplace equation, then automatically
$$f_{\nu}(\rho)=C_{\nu}J_{\nu}(k\rho)+D_{\nu}Y_{\nu}(k\rho).$$

The coefficients $C_{\nu}$ and $D_{\nu}$ can be identified by comparing the asymptotics of $f_{\nu}(\rho)$ defined by (1) as $\rho\to 0$ or $\rho\to \infty$ with the [known behavior of Bessel functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Asymptotic_forms).

Comment: I forgot to specify, I know that my particular function is symmetric wrt $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: I do not understand how I would 'compare the asymptotics'

Comment: @grdgfgr I have extended the answer. Is it more clear now?

Comment: I do not understand what good 'comparing' would do once an infinite number of $J\nu$ and $Y\nu$ are added together. With what device am I suppose to compare?

Comment: I understand now what you mean

Comment: @grdgfgr I forgot to mention that one does not necessarily need to use the asymptotics. For example, one could compute $f_{\nu}(\rho)$ at some values $\rho=R_1$, $\rho=R_2$ and solve the resulting system of two linear equations for $C_{\nu}$, $D_{\nu}$.

Comment: I failed to realize that once I had taken the fourier series, the bessel functions would no longer be mixed together.

Comment: I'd like to clarify what you meant by $1-\cos^2 (\phi)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\cos(2\phi)}{2}$. It is not a single frequency. It would have to be decomposed into $J_0(k\rho)$ and $J_2(k\rho)\cos(2\phi)$, which do not satisfy the laplaces equation separately, which I though it should. (I tried decomposing my function and indeed the even coefficients are all 0)

Comment: @grdgfgr In fact this function does not satisfy Laplace equation. I just used it as an example to illustrate that vanishing at finite number of points does not guarantee that the function is odd.